# Add a subview after a few seconds

Tags: swift

I have this code:

```
 UIView.animateWithDuration(0.6, delay: 5.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6, initialSpringVelocity: 3.0, options: nil, animations: {

     self.view.addSubview(self.label!)

},completion: nil)
```

But it doesn't look like that the label is placed after 5.0 seconds. In the app you see it immediately.

How can i fix the problem that the label will be placed after 5 seconds?

Comment: Use dispatch_after instead if you aren't animating any properties

Comment: Adding a subview is not animatable. Either `dispatch_after` or add it immediately with `alpha` of `0` and then animate the change of `alpha` to `1` inside the `animateWithDuration` block.

Comment: + it will be better that you will add the view before the animation block with 0 alpha and animate the alpha in the block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bear in mind that with `animateWithDuration()` - (in the MVC pattern) - the View animation takes time to execute but the Model changes immediately and not after the given duration.

Use this function

```
func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
        dispatch_after(
            dispatch_time(
                DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
            ),
            dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
```

for example to add a subview after a certain delay:

```
delay(5.0, closure: {self.view.addSubview(self.label!)})
```